# How to wait for http response to assign value?

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to execute a block of code *outside of a function* based on a variable obtained from a $http GET request but I'm struggling to achieve this.

```
$scope.myBooleanVariable = $http.get("url...");

if ($scope.myBooleanVariable) { // undefined
//perform something that must be outside of a function
}
```

This is a basic example of what I'm attempting to do, but with the http request being asynchronous the if case is always undefined(falsy). Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: For Angular in particular, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37586557/3773011). However, the other higher-voted answers do a better job at explaining the concepts, but don't directly have examples for Angular. What you appear to be missing here are the concepts as much as the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a promise handler with a success/error callback to await the response. In the inner function you can access the variables from the outside.

In Angular.js you can do it like:

```
$scope.myValue = null;

$http.get("url...").$promise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.myValue = response;
  console.log(response);
  // do your logic, myValue is now defined
});
```

Comment: I specifically mentioned that the logic I want to execute should not be in a function, as is the case if you use .then(function(...

Comment: Why do you *specifically* have that restriction? But if you do, the answer is simple: It is not possible. The request is asynchronous and you need to execute the logic in a callback. You could use syntactical sugar with `await` which makes it look like it is not in a function, but internally it is exactly the same. Like mentioned in my answer, you can access the outer scope from within a function, so you don't have any drawbacks when using a function.